# Can a function return a dataframe or list in python?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I am writing a function to use the information of each row in a dataframe to select some observations in another dataframe and return a dataframe or list:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({"D": [10,20,30], "p": [20, 30, 10]})

  df1 = pd.DataFrame({"W": [20,30,30], "G": [10, 40, 10]})

  def Compute(row):

      df1.State = df1.apply(lambda r: 1 if r.W > row['D'] else 0, axis = 1)

      df2 = df1[ (df1.State == 1) ]

      if len(df2) > 0:

           return df2

 df.apply(Compute, axis = 1)
```

But, I am always getting an error like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<ipython-input-96-c5fdc35977db>", line 1, in <module>
df.apply(Compute, axis = 1)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3972, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4081, in _apply_standard
    result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 226, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
dtype=dtype)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5163, in _arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5477, in _homogenize
    raise_cast_failure=False)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2887, in _sanitize_array
    subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

    File "C:\Users\Research\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 2011, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]

    ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3
```

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: Can you put a complete stacktrace

Comment: `def f(x): return x` returns a dataframe or a list if it is fed a dataframe or a list, so the answer to the title question is trivially "yes".

Comment: I added the traceback to my question.

Comment: Yes, but when I want to run the function on each row, I am getting the above error.

Comment: What you added is not **complete**. It includes parts of the traceback, but not the exception itself.

Comment: BTW, there's no need for all the extra linebreaks in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner. I edited the traceback part. This is what I see in my output.

Comment: I only showed part of the data set. Because it's huge, I want to use a function.